# Buck/Boost evaluation board buzzing/ringing sound

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, stability

I'm currently modifying [this buck/boost evaluation board](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu465/snvu465.pdf) to output a range of voltages between ~1.5 V and 12 V. In order to achieve this, I've replaced R14 in the feedback voltage divider with a 20 kohm resistor (see page 10 in the above user guide), thus "tricking" the board into permanently compensating the output voltage to a stable 1.5 V. I've also soldered a digital potentiometer in parallel with R22 in order to draw current from the feedback node, which causes the output voltage to rise depending on the resistance of the digital pot.

I've already done these things and the system is working... to a point. The load that I'm driving is a ~1.8 ohm heating coil, so high current is inevitable. The buck/boost is rated to output a maximum of 10 A at its original 12 V output so I figured I wouldn't have any issues. However, when I connect 12 V at the input and decrease the digital potentiometer resistance to increase the output voltage, the eval board starts to buzz/ring loudly and persistently. This happens when the output gets up to  7.0 V and the current through the coil is about 3.9 A. The voltage across the coil also begins to grow unstable at around this time, varying in voltage about 500 mV.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this issue or what the origin of the noise is? My guess is it's coming from the switching element in the buck/boost. If that's the case is there any way to get rid of the noise?

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

[image]

Comment: Without schematic and waveforms all is just guesses

Comment: People here don't like to follow links so I added the schematic for you.

Comment: ringing is often a saturating magnetic element.

Comment: Ringing at what frequency?

Comment: Since you're using the converter for a different output voltage the value of the inductor and/or saturation current might not be correct anymore. Look in the datasheet of the LM5175 and use it to re-calculate the value of the inductor for your configuration. Also watch the saturation current of the inductor.

Comment: captain it's too much, she can't take anymore!

Comment: Does it work if you replace the digipot with a suitable resistor value?